# get the coordinates of a FrameworkElement bounding rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, f#

How does one get the upper left coordinates of a framework elements bounding rectangle?

```
    let fe : FrameworkElement = ea.Item.Content 
    let p = fe.TranslatePoint(new Point(0.0, 0.0), null)
```

The preceding code is giving me: The field, constructor or member 'TranslatePoint' is not defined.  I am confused as MSDN Shows this as a memeber of FrameworkElement inherited from UIElement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement_members(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `element.TranslatePoint(new Point(0.0, 0.0), null)` to get the upper left coordinates of `element` relative to the logical root element. If you want it relative to another element, specify it at the second parameter instead of `null`. You can then use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` to compute the whole rectangle.

Comment: The field, constructor or member 'TranslatePoint' is not defined

Comment: It is defined in WPF. In Silverlight, you must use `element.TransformToVisual(root).Transform(new Point(0.0, 0.0))`.

Comment: Bingo! Do you know why that is?

Comment: I suppose that methods that are just shortcuts to other methods are not present in Silverlight to avoid bloating the assembly.

Comment: Doesn't work very well for me. I'm getting incorrect positions in a grid.